# Signing Android apk : INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES

Tags: java, android, processing

I'm trying to sign an Android apk created using Processing.

Here's what I did (based on this : http://www.akeric.com/blog/?p=1352 ) :

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore myapp-release-key.keystore -alias myname -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

ant release

jarsigner -verbose -keystore myapp-release-key.keystore <PATH>/android/bin/<APPNAME>-release-unsigned.apk myname

jarsigner -verify <PATH>/android/bin/<APPNAME>-release-unsigned.apk

zipalign -v 4 bin/<APPNAME>-release-unsigned.apk bin/<APPNAME>-release.apk

adb install bin/<APPNAME>-release.apk
```

But I get an error :

```
INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES
```

The jarsigner verify terminated with :

```
s = signature was verified 
m = entry is listed in manifest
k = at least one certificate was found in keystore
i = at least one certificate was found in identity scope

jar verified.

Warning: 
    This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is not validated.
    This jar contains signatures that does not include a timestamp. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2042-09-08) or after any future revocation date.
```

Any ideas as to what's wrong? Something to do with those warnings?

Comment: Did you rebuild your app with `./gradlew build` ?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you add the following 2 options: `-sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1` to your jarsigner command even though you've already specified something similar when generating the key. Like that:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore myapp-release-key.keystore <PATH>/android/bin/<APPNAME>-release-unsigned.apk myname
```

Took me AGES to realise these were NOT optional... Doc definitely un-clear on that one.

Hope that helps. Good luck.